# PyCharm, save font size after exit

Tags: pycharm

Is it possible to save font size (per file)  after exit at PyCharm?
Currently after I close PyCharm and open it again, the font size (per file) is returned to default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just go to **File | Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Font**

At first the option is disabled because it is not allowed to edit bundled scheme. To *enable* it just create your own scheme based on any of the bundled ones (click the *Save As* button next to *Scheme Name*):

[image]

Comment: I tried, to change in **Preferences | Editor |  Colors & Fonts | Font**  (In my version, there is no **Settings** in **File** menu) but after closing PyCharm or reboot, the font size (per file) is not saved.